# Selenium on click site returns to similar state and stale error

Tags: python, selenium

I'm scraping [this](http://www.tripadvisor.ca/Attractions-g147288-Activities-c42-Dominican_Republic.html) site using selenium. Firstly, i clicked on the clear button beside Attraction Type. Then i clicked on the more link on the bottom of the category list . Now for each i find the element by id and click on the link. The problem is as i click on the first category Outdoor Activities, the website goes back to the initial state again and i get following error as i try to click the next link:

```
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element is no longer attached to the DOM
```

My code is:

```
class TripSpider(CrawlSpider):
  name = "tspider"
  allowed_domains = ["tripadvisor.ca"]
  start_urls = ['http://www.tripadvisor.ca/Attractions-g147288-Activities-c42-Dominican_Republic.html']

  def __init__(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.driver.maximize_window()


  def parse(self, response):
    self.driver.get(response.url)
    self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('filter_clear').click()
    time.sleep(3)
    self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('show').click()
    time.sleep(3)
    #to handle popups
    self.driver.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[-1])
    # Close the new window
    self.driver.close()
    # Switch back to original browser (first window)
    self.driver.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[0])
    divs = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[contains(@id,"ATTR_CATEGORY")]')
    for d in divs:
      d.find_element_by_tag_name('a').click()
      time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: why do you have sleeps in your code?  that's not how you wait for elements in webdriver

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg so should i use waits ?

Comment: your latest edit is swallowing NoSuchElementException... I doubt you really want to do that.

Comment: also, please post the entire stacktrace so we know where the error is coming from.  And stop editing the code in your question.. it's hard to debug a moving target,

Comment: you now have debugging (print) statements and syntax errors (indentation) in your code.  It differs from your original question.

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg back to original code. I get stack trace on d.find_element_by_tag_name('a').click() section

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg not any help with implicit wait

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this website in particular is that each time you click on an element the DOM changes, so you can`t loop through elements which have gone stale.

I have the same problem short time ago, and I solved it using different windows for each link.

You could change this part of the code:

```
divs = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[contains(@id,"ATTR_CATEGORY")]')
for d in divs:
    d.find_element_by_tag_name('a').click()
    time.sleep(3)
```

For:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
mainWindow = self.driver.current_window_handle
divs = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[contains(@id,"ATTR_CATEGORY")]')
for d in divs:
    # Open the element in a new Window
    d.find_element_by_tag_name('a').send_keys(Keys.SHIFT + Keys.ENTER)
    self.driver.switch_to_window(self.driver.window_handles[1])

    # Here you do whatever you want in the new window

    # Close the window and continue
    self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w')
    self.driver.switch_to_window(mainWindow)
```

Comment: i tried the shift + enter even ctrl + enter technique but it updates in the same page even in normal condition rather than opening in new window

Comment: Did you combine the implicit wait from the other comments with this approach? I can't understand why it doesn't even open a new window...